# Send a missed call-Android program

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to write a android application  which can send sb a missed call. It means that application call to sb by about 5 second.
I know that this code start calling.

```
private void call() {

    try {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));

        startActivity(callIntent);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed", e);

    }

}
```

But I dont know how to stop it(after 5 second)?

Ps.This question have got mark -1 because question is stupid or my english is bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this because once you start the callIntent, the control will go to the calling application.

But there are workarounds to do this by getting the `ITelephony` object of `TelephonyManager`using java reflection.

```
     TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     try {
            Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
       }catch(Exception e){}

       telephonyService.endCall();
```

source:
[call-control-in-android](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a delay Handler and make a new call to self after you have made the call to your target number. Hoping this is not for spam purposes which is frowned upon. In your code snipplet or loop you can have the below

```
if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {//targetMSISDN the phone no you are calling out to


                    String dial = "tel:" + targetMSISDN;
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));
                    //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial))); 

                    //delay a drop call
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Do something after 10000ms

                            Toast.makeText(YourNotSpamActivity.this, "Calling me to end you!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //end call now

                            String TAG="ERR:";
                            try {

                                Log.v(TAG, "Get getTeleService...");
                                if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {

                                    String dial = "tel:YourPhoneNumber";
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));//call yourself to terminate the first call
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e(TAG,
                                        "FATAL ERROR: couldn't call ");
                                Log.e(TAG, "Exception object: " + e);
                            }
                        }
                    }, 10000);

                    //end the end call
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(YourNotSpamActivity.this, "Permission Call Phone denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```